# $post->ID returning wrong value

Tags: wordpress

The ID that should be returned is 3001 instead i keep getting 2896?

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'cv','post_author' => $user_id, 'post_title' => $page_user));

if( $query->have_posts() ){
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        echo $post_id;

$exists = 1;
} else {
$exists = 0;
}
```

Any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
<?php 
$postid = get_the_ID(); 
?> 

or

<?php
 $postid = get_post($id);
?>
```

I think it may be helpful for u

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the **while loop** with `the_post()` part. Adapt partial code according this example:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) : 
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  //crucial part  
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        echo $post_id;
     endwhile; 

     $exists = 1;

else :
     $exists = 0;
endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'cv','post_author' => $user_id, 'post_title' => 
$page_user));
while(have_posts())
{
if( $query->have_posts() ){
$post_id = $post->ID;
echo $post_id;
$exists = 1;
} else {
$exists = 0;
} 
}
```